# PHP - Loop through UNION ALL query and separate items by category

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a union query which joins several categories.

The query goes like:

```
SELECT Item FROM table WHERE category = 1 LIMI 10
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM table WHERE category = 2 LIMIT 6
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM table WHERE category = 3 LIMIT 11
```

... the result is

```
Item 1 - Category 1
Item 2 - Category 1
Item 3 - Category 1
Item 4 - Category 2
Item 5 - Category 2
Item 6 - Category 3
```

Now when I loop it, I cannot get the number of items per category to separate them via modulo for example because the number of items per category is not always the same.

The output should be like this:

```
Category 1
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
Category 2
- Item 4
- Item 5
Category 3
- Item 6
```

the loop should be like:

```
foreach ($query as $row)
{
  echo $row['category'] . "<br>"; // This should be included only once per category with all items printed.
  echo 'Item name:' . $row['item'] . "<br>"; // This should repeat depending how many times items are found in the category.
}
```

Comment: Change the select to `SELECT category, Item FROM table....`  Then in your PHP code you should be able to get the desired output.

Comment: I already did include all fields, but in foreach loop, when i echo category it repeats X times instead just once and get separated by category

Comment: Then change the foreach loop, so it does not echo all the returned fields?

Comment: Added how foreach loop should look like. It should echo all returned items, but category should be added only once at top per items from that category, not every time item in that category is found.

Comment: "Added how foreach loop should look like", NO It should not look like that, because you only want to return the category when it is different then the previous version of it.

Comment: Yes, but I can not find a way to do it via if statement to limit it for 1 repetition only when category changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$c = "";
foreach ($query as $row)
{
  if ($c!=$row['category']) {
     echo $row['category'] . "<br>"; 
     $c = $row['category'];
  }
  echo 'Item name:' . $row['item'] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I also tried to do same thing but adding an text below `echo 'Item name:' . $row['item'] . "<br>";` like go to category: X, but its not adding the text after the last item in that category for some reason.

Comment: That would be a new question, post it together with the desired output, and the tag `php`.

Comment: Will do it in 90 minutes due to cooldown. Thank you

Comment: I will start my stopwatch....   (no, seriously, i will not.....)

Comment: Hehe I guess that would be a cron-watch :D